# Trying to access both a json from google places api and then access the photo reference returned by this json

Tags: php

I'm currently working with the google places api to display a list of restaurants near a users location. The json returns the names of the restaurants along with details and a string that represents a photo reference. In order to actually get the picture itself you need to put the reference string in google's place photos api, as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos). I thought I coded everything correctly but the json I'm getting from the place photos api is null and I can't figure out why.

```js
define("PLACES_API_ENDPOINT", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaraunts+near".$address);

$curl1 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, PLACES_API_ENDPOINT . "&key=my key");

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl1);

/*echo "<hr>";*/
//var_dump($response);

$response = json_decode($response, true);

echo "<hr>";
var_dump($response);
echo "<hr>";
var_dump($response["results"][0]["photos"][0]["photo_reference"]);
$photoReference=$response["results"][0]["photos"][0]["photo_reference"];


define("PHOTOS_API_ENDPOINT", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=".$photoReference);

$curl2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_URL, PHOTOS_API_ENDPOINT . "&key=my key");

curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$responsePhoto = curl_exec($curl2);

/*echo "<hr>";*/
//var_dump($response);

$responsePhoto = json_decode($responsePhoto, true);

echo "<hr>";
var_dump($responsePhoto);
echo "<hr>";
```

Comment: What is the value of `$responsePhoto` before you try to `json_decode` it?

Comment: I tried echoing it out and a link popped up that said "302 Moved the document has moved here" and the link sends me to the image. However, I would Like the image itself to appear on this page, if that is possible. @GregSchmidt

Comment: To have cURL follow the 302, use the [FOLLOWLOCATION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html) option.

Comment: What will FOLLOWLOCATION return exactly? A url to the image or the image itself because I want to take each image and insert it into the src of an html img.

Comment: Seems like this is the sort of question that the documentation I linked might address, or that you could find the answer to more quickly by trying it than by asking the internet.